# Resetting Observables - am I doing it right?

Tags: knockout.js

Every once in a while, I have an observable that I need to "reset" to it's default value, such as when I've just sent some new data to the server and I get a success postback.  I usually do this:

```
 self.dataToSend = ko.observable();
 self.dataToSend(self.getPayload());
 // send data, in success promise do this:
 self.dataToSend = ko.observable();
```

Is there anything wrong with this approach?  Will garbage collection pick up the old observables from memory automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. This is creating a *new* observable.

This *new* observable is *not* the same observable that has been bound in previous bindings - either via 'data-bind' or in other observable dependency graphs. That is, the code effectively *breaks* KO's observable model.

Compare with `self.dataToSend(undefined)` which reuses the *same* observable.

In some [rare] cases it may make sense to have an observable *of* an observable - but the outer container observable should still be reassigned via an observable write.

---

As far are observable lifetime: by creating a new observable and assigning it as a property, the previous observable is no longer strongly reachable via that property .. *however*, the "old" observable is still referenced from all previously established observable dependency graphs and thus does not likely to limit the lifetime of the "old" observable object or otherwise make it eligible for reclamation by the GC.

Thus, short of removing the *entire* related observable dependency graph, it's better to just update the same observable which will avoid creating disconnected orphan dependents.